# Functions to get percentage from 3 different values

Tags: linear-transformations, percentages

I can't figure out how to create 2 linear functions that takes as input a value between 0 and 180 (always) and returns a percentage using 3 values :

a1, b1 and c1 used by the first function

And a2, b2 and c2 used by the second function

**The first function (Image 1) :**

if the value is b1 --> return 100%

if the value is a1 --> return 0%

if the value is c1 --> return 0%

**The second function (Image 2) :**

if the value is b2 --> return 0%

if the value is a2 --> return 100%

if the value is c2 --> return 100%

[image: Image 1 & image 2]

Comment: You would have to use piecewise linear functions for this. For instance, if you want a linear function that has $f(a) = 0 $ and $f(b) = 1$, you could use
$$
f(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}
$$
And if you want to in addition have  $f(c)=0$, you have to make this a piecewise function with a condition (something like "if $x$ is larger than $b$ ...")

Comment: But if i use the second image for example: and i choise : a2 = 4, b2 = 86, c2 = 176, and i want to calculate f(179) i get  : (179-86)/(176-86)  =  103% and that's not what i am loking for to get, for 179 i should get approximately  95% o 94 %(I didn't calcultate it)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying: if you want all the parts to be linear (and not for example polynomial), you will have to use piecewise linear functions. I have not made any for you as of yet. The equation that I gave you is just an example of what a piecewise function would be, but only when $a \leq x \leq b$. The rest you should make yourself.

Comment: I think i get it. For the each image i have to create 4 functions (4 conditions), when x is between 0 and a1, when it's between a1 and b1, and when it's between b1 and c1 and when it's between c1 and 180.

Comment: markup=1/(1-margin)-1 and margin=1-1/(1+markup)